# How to remove empty space before create .txt file

Tags: c#

My Code:

```
private void genFile()
    {
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        String sql = "";

        sql = "SELECT TOP(1) start_rg, end_rg FROM Range WHERE status = 'Available' ";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        using (StreamWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"..\Range\Range.txt"))
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                tw.WriteLine("Range");
                tw.WriteLine("StartRange= {0}", dataRead["start_rg"]);
                tw.WriteLine("EndRange= {0}", dataRead["end_rg"]);
            }
        }
        dataReader.Close();
        command.Dispose();
    }
```

when the .txt file has been created, there are white spaces between the = sign and the data that being fetch from database. i've already check the data in the database. there are no space in front of the data

this is the example of txt file that has been created

[txt file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raTw0.png)

how to remove the white space before creating the txt file?

Comment: Remove the space here: `"StartRange= {0}"` => `"StartRange={0}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white space is there since you have a white space after "=" and before "{". In other words, you are adding it.

If you remove these, it should work as you expect it to.

from:

```
            tw.WriteLine("StartRange= {0}", dataRead["start_rg"]);
            tw.WriteLine("EndRange= {0}", dataRead["end_rg"]);
```

to:

```
            tw.WriteLine("StartRange={0}", dataRead["start_rg"]);
            tw.WriteLine("EndRange={0}", dataRead["end_rg"]);
```